# Add margin-bottom to all column elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In a bootstrap 3 project i've wanted some borders around cols so I made the following css [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9987/).

```
.admin-div{

    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding:20px;
}
```

When I use it I place it inside a col like:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
     <div class="admin-div">
     </div>
 </div>
```

This works fine on big screens but on small screens there is no margin (**note:** the most left doesnt have the custom admin-div class and is a default list-group).

**Large screen** (nice margins beteween col's)

[image: Large screen]

**Small screen** (no margin between col's)

[image: Small]

One options is add

```
margin-bottom:20px
```

to all sm and sx elements but that sounds a bit overkill.

I could use

```
 @media (max-width: 970px) { .spacing-div{ margin-bottom: 20px; } }
```

But than I have to add an extra class to all divs where I have a col.

So i have two solutions but they both feel like they could be replaced by something much more easy.
What is the best way to make 
**all col's** have a margin-bottom :20px; even on small screens?

**The extra admin-div is only to show the problem, without the extra div I would still have the problem but it wouldnt be visible that much.**

Comment: you may find your solution here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Comment: Can you put your whole page on JSfiddle?

Comment: @Blkc added a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9987/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a margin on absolutely every column in Bootstrap you could use the following CSS selector which will add a margin to every element that contains `col-`.

```css
[class*=col-] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

You could also use `[class^=col-]` in which the first class on an element needs to began with `col-`.

To extend this a bit further you could use a media query to have it only apply up to a certain screen size.

```css
[class*=col-] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
@media ( min-width: 500px ) {
    [class*=col-] {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

If you didn't want a margin on every single column then I would scope the above with a modifier selector.

```html
<div class="row modifier">
    <div class="col-6-md"></div>
    <div class="col-6-md"></div>
</div>
```

```css
/* fairly general - all columns in .modifier */
.modifier [class*=col-] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/* a little more specific - only .col-md-6 columns in .modifier */
.modifier [class*=col-md-6] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```